Why is it thought that Moses was only a Priest for 7 days?
Moses is unique in the Hebrew Bible as the only Priest-King of Israel. There is also, of course, Melchizedek and probably some pagan Priest-Kings of other nations in the bible as well. Something that I've learned since I've started participating on this forum is that one traditional belief is that Moses only temporarily held the position of (High) Priest for 7 days or so whilst he ordained Aaron - at which point he supposedly ceased to be a priest.
Some here have claimed this transfer of the priesthood to be "obvious," but as one who has read through the scriptures many times and been unaware of this tradition - I do not find it obvious in the least. Moses continued to intercede for the people and for Aaron after Aaron was made the High Priest, he instructed Aaron on how to perform his duties and rebuked him, and it was Moses who went into the Tent of Meeting before God throughout the wilderness - thereby causing his face to glow and thus requiring him to use a veil to cover himself so as to not scare the people. Moses was also declared to be Elohim whilst Aaron was made his prophet. Thus, based upon the scriptures, it seems rather clear that Moses both served as a Priest for much longer than a week - and that he was higher than Aaron even when he became High Priest.
But I am open to correction and would like to know the reasoning behind the assertion that Moses was only temporarily a priest despite his continued role of interceding for the people - including Aaron? How would you argue this position? And are there competing views on this within Judaism, or is this the de-facto standard belief?
Thanks :)

When we say that Moses did not remain a “priest” past those seven days, it means that he did not have the “Halachic status” of a “Kohen” i.e. someone who can offer the sacrifices in the Holy Temple.

@Sholom I see. I suppose if a priest is understood as one who directly sacrifices animals then that makes sense. Although, it seems to me that the sacrifices were functionally the means by which the priests interceded for the people. Moses did this without needing to sacrifice.

@RyanPierceWilliams look at Rashi there, he gives a nice explanation- Moshe was originally supposed to be the High Priest but when he asked G-d to have his brother speak to Pharoh, he lost the job offer

I do agree with that; I’ve thought myself that Aaron probably wouldn’t have had much of a role at all if Moses hadn’t tried to get out of it in the first place.

@Sholom I think you're right - the misunderstanding here is a matter of definition. The term "priest" on this website is synonymous with the halachic term "kohen"

@RyanPierceWilliams "Although, it seems to me that the sacrifices were functionally the means by which the priests interceded for the people." Nah. Moshe did that on his own, repeatedly. Once he sent Aharon to do it with incense. Re-examine that assumption.

@MichoelR Which, again, demonstrates Moses’ superiority to Aaron. Moses spoke with God directly and could intercede for the people by talking and reasoning with God. Aaron and the priests, on the other hand, were given detailed instructions on how to perform sacrifices for the people to address their guilt and (unintentional) sins. They got the Umim and Thumim to divine God’s will.

All maybe true, but not relevant to your question. Moshe did what he did, and what you are calling "priests" was a different job description. You seem to be assuming something about that term which is probably just a mistranslation.

@MichoelR or just an interpretative difference of what it means to be a priest. My view of a priest is one who serves God as an intermediary between God and men, interceding for men and serving as a moral guide for the community - teaching them to obey God’s commands. Sacrifices are part of this - and a big part of the Aaronic Priesthood - but not necessarily the most significant part. After all, we are told God prefers obedience over sacrifice.

That's a fine view, but it may have nothing to do with what the gemara means when it talks about when Moshe was a Cohen and when he wasn't.

@MichoelR that’s fair. I guess I need to learn Hebrew so that I can properly investigate the matter  I was going to put it off until I was more solid in my Koine Greek, but I’m starting to think there’s more benefit to investing my time in Hebrew

See Zevahim 102a where a number of opinions are quoted:

Moses was originally meant to be a priest, but the priesthood was taken away from him and given to Aaron;
Moses was only ever meant to act as a priest during the seven days of inaugurating the Tabernacle;
Moses remained a priest his whole life, but his children were not priests.


The primary office of Moses is Prophet. Thus, more like Elijah than Aaron. Here is another opinion for you: Moses never occupied the office of King but rather the office of Judge (like Ehud).

I'm pretty sure when you go through the scriptures you can find many cases of Propets who acted like Priests in some manner or other; I am drawn to Elijah here but it's a poor fit.
